# Ionic 4 push notification without local notification

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic4

I'm facing the next problem. I want to turn off showing notification alert (local notification) while the app is in foreground mode on Android and iOS. I just want to catch the push notification in the code but without showing it in the notification bar. Actually, I just need a trigger when notification is received and nothing else.

I've implemented firebase using this tutorial:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-push-notifications-working-with-ionic-4-and-firebase-ad87cc92394e

To understand me better, I have next situation. I have a list of some data and when the push notification comes I want to refresh the list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When the application is in foreground mode, I think the trigger when receiving the notification is this part from **app.component.ts**:

```
this.fcm.onNotifications().subscribe(...)
```

where **onNotifications()** is part of **fcm.service.ts**:

```
onNotifications() {
    return this.firebase.onNotificationOpen();
}
```

maybe, instead of showing the toast, you could refresh the list?